# Why does writing to AWS Keyspaces with spark-cassandra-connector return "Unsupported partitioner"?

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, amazon-keyspaces

I'm trying to write some data in aws keyspace with spark, but the follow message error shows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: \
  Unsupported partitioner: com.amazonaws.cassandra.DefaultPartitioner
```

Being so, I tried to write the same data with Java pure client and I had success.
I looked which dependencies spark has, and for my suprise are the same then java client pure (Java-driver).

Why java has been success write and spark not ? Can be some about connection ? Auth ?

Answer (score 3):

AWS Keyspaces uses a proprietary partitioner class `com.amazonaws.cassandra.DefaultPartitioner` which isn't available in open-source Apache Cassandra. It works with the Java driver because it is possible to use custom partitioner classes with the driver.

However, the [Spark-Cassandra connector only supports two partitioners](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/partitioner/dht/TokenFactory.scala#L90-L91):

- `Murmur3Partitioner`
- `RandomPartitioner`

You won't be able to use the Spark connector on AWS Keyspaces since their `DefaultPartitioner` is not supported.

The Spark connector does not support Cassandra forks or CQL API variants so we don't run tests against them. Cheers!

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/working-with-partitioners.html

Answer (score 2):

Keyspaces now supports the RandomPartitioner, which enables reading and writing data between Keyspaces and Apache Spark by using the open-source Spark Cassandra Connector. You just have to update the partitioner for your account.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/spark-integrating.html

Launch announcement: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/04/amazon-keyspaces-read-write-data-apache-spark/